# Angular Reactive Form Automatic Group Validation According to Controls

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm not sure if this is the intended behaviour; I have the following:

```js
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
  name: this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: ['', Validators.required]
  })
});
```

```html
<div formGroupName="name">
  <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
  <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
</div>
```

When I submit the form and `console.log(this.formGroup)`, the `errors` object of the `name` `AbstractControl` is null. I expected it should have an `Object` with `required: true`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If the field is valid, then errors is `null`. This is just how it is :)

Comment: But both child fields are empty!

Comment: Ah okay, you didn't mention that ;)

Comment: Where do you use `formGroup` in your template?

Comment: Inside a `div` inside another `div` inside a `form` html element. Did I understand your question?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10530 Here is plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/B6vm3m6CZ170kijAOQaF?p=preview As we can see the `errors` are not bubbling

Comment: Oh wow, I see. What would you think is a workaround, to simply implement a group validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @yurzui for pointing out the related [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10530) -- this is a workaround that will simply check for both controls:

```js
import {AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';

export const nameValidator = (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} => {
 const firstName = control.get('firstName');
 const lastName = control.get('lastName');
 if (!firstName || !lastName) {
  return null;
 }
 return firstName.value && lastName.value ? null : { required: true };
};
```

This needs to be explicitly included as a validator of course:

```html
name: this.fb.group({
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', Validators.required]
}, {validator: nameValidator}),
```